# How to calculate and change treeview width

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, treeview

How to let the `TreeView` to change its width when expanding node so that the label of node will completely show.

First I set the `DrawMode = OwnerDrawAll;`

Then handle the event `DrawNode` andin handler

```
e.DrawDefault = true;
currentWith_ = Math.Max(currentWith_, e.Node.Bounds.Right);
```

and then in `AfterExpand` sets the control with. But is not works every time. Sometimes the with is not changed or changed not correctly.

How to correct this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And What have You Tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one, this works successfully:

```
private void treeViewAfterExpand(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    int maxRight = treeView.ClientSize.Width;

    if(e.Node.Nodes != null)
        foreach (TreeNode node in e.Node.Nodes)
        {
            maxRight = Math.Max(maxRight, node.Bounds.Right);
        }

    treeView.ClientSize = new Size(maxRight, treeView.ClientSize.Height);
}
```

Comment: `treeView.Bounds` is the `treeView.ClientSize` added borders and etc.

Comment: Don't work!!!! Only first node in the collection have Bounds property to set, another values is set to 0.

Comment: Each node in a tree has the bounds-property. You just have to set the size of the treeview to the maximun-bound-width.

Comment: Are you tried? They have Bounds property, but its properties (Width, Height,...) sets to 0!

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by Ria works, but not when expanding in the constructor. Expanding in the load event instead of the constructor made it work. (Could not comment because lower then 50 points.)

Comment: Solution does not work also in `OnLoad` constructor. Is there bug or issue? Is there workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't take into acount hidden/collapsed nodes.

To make it more interesting, suppose that your TreeView (tvSamples) is in the left of a SplitContainer (scTree) and you want to adjust the width of the SplitContainer to fit the contents of the TreeView when the nodes are expanded/collapsed and also when the form resizes (which dynamically changes the SplitterDistance):

```
 Private TREEVIEWPADDING As Integer = 10
 Private Sub treeViewAfterExpand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles tvSamples.AfterExpand

     scTree.SplitterDistance = TreeViewWidth(tvSamples.Nodes, 0) + TREEVIEWPADDING

 End Sub
 Private Function TreeViewWidth(node As TreeNode, maxwidth As Integer) As Integer

     If node.IsVisible Then
         If node.Nodes IsNot Nothing Then
             Return Max(maxwidth, TreeViewWidth(node.Nodes, maxwidth))
         Else
             Return Max(maxwidth, node.Bounds.Right)
         End If
     Else
         Return maxwidth
     End If

 End Function
 Private Function TreeViewWidth(nodes As TreeNodeCollection, maxwidth As Integer) As Integer

     Dim result As Integer = maxwidth
     For Each node As TreeNode In nodes
         If node.IsVisible Then
             result = Max(result, TreeViewWidth(node, node.Bounds.Right))
         End If
     Next
     Return result

 End Function
 Private Sub Form1_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ResizeEnd

     scTree.SplitterDistance = TreeViewWidth(tvSamples.Nodes, 0) + scPaths.SplitterWidth + TREEVIEWPADDING

 End Sub
```